# Why the 'post' method is not working in my django app?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I am using Django to develop a blog and when I wanted to get the contact informations, the post request seems not working at all. In the contacts view I don't do much I just wanted to make sure that the post request is working but it returns a Get request instead and the get method is working really fine
**the javascript file**

```
  //CONTACT FORM
$('#contactform').submit(function(){
  var action = $(this).attr('action');
  $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
  $('#message').hide();
  $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
  $.post(action, {
    name: $('#name').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    comments: $('#comments').val()
  },
    function(data){
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
      $('#message').slideDown('slow');
      $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');
      $(window).trigger('resize');
    }
  );
  });
  return false;
});
```

**view.py**

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from contact.forms import ContactForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
# Create your views here.
def contacts(request):
if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax:
    print('hello!!')
    
    return render(request, 'contact/contact.html')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Contact
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
     class Meta:
         model = Contact
         fields = ['cont_name', 'cont_email', 'cont_message', 'cont_date']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Contact(models.Model):
    cont_name = models.CharField( max_length = 10)
    cont_email = models.EmailField()
    cont_message = models.TextField(blank=False)
    cont_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cont_name
```

**contact.html**

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <p class="lead">Sold old ten are quit lose deal his sent. You correct how sex several far distant believe journey parties. We shyness enquire uncivil affixed it carried to. </p>
              <p>End sitting shewing who saw besides son musical adapted. Contrasted interested eat alteration pianoforte sympathize was. He families believed if no elegance interest surprise an. It abode wrong miles an so delay plate.</p>
              
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div id="message"></div>
              <form method="post" action="{% url 'contacts' %}" id="ContactForm" class="main-contact-form wow">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-4" name="name" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." />
                  <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-4" name="email" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." />
                  <textarea name="comments" class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="Your Message *" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-theme" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" />
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, reverse
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.contacts, name= 'contacts'),
```

]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Specifically, what does "seems not working at all" mean? What HTTP code do you get back? Does it come with error messages? What do you see in your logs? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague but it seems you want to make work an ajax post request in django.
Can you try this:

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(){
  var action = $(this).attr('action');
  
  var name = $("#name").val()
  var email = $("email").val()
  var formData = {
    name: name,
    email: email
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    url:action,
    beforeSend: function (data) {

    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data){
            console.log("Working")
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
     console.log("Not working")
   }

  })
  })
```

See if this works.

Comment: Thank you! I used the code you gave me and still, the post request won't work it gives a get request instead:   [25/Dec/2020 12:26:33] "GET /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9322
[25/Dec/2020 12:29:10] "GET /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9322       normally in this case and according to my view it should write hello and a post request not a Get I still can't figure it out

Comment: I saw your url patterns... From what I get whenever u r going to the home page say http://localhost:8000 this contacts URL with a get request is hit which you r handling properly... I mean only if it's a post request then log some things in the js file inside submit function and see if on submitting form anything is printed on the console or not.

Comment: If all this is checked properly then try switching post request to get request and then in the views see for request.method == POST and request.is_ajax. This thing will make sure if the Ajax request is working or not for only post request which I am clear from your question. One last thing that you can do is Django provides a snippet that u have to plug in while making a card request with Ajax. If you have not done this already try plugging in the snippet and run the code.

Comment: I am not sure I got what you said exactly because honestly, I used a Bootstrap template, and I dunno anything about the javaScript side. The original template has PHP files that handle the research and the contact part in the template and first when I did not touch the JS code, running the code would post a nonexisting PHP file, and then when I run the code you suggested it would return just a Get not a post